# “You look good. The last time I seen you, you looked terrible, your head was busted in and —”

Tags: meaning

> “You look good. The last time I seen you, you looked terrible, your
>   head was busted in and —”

What's a "busted in" hairstyle?

Research I've done https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=busted+in+head&btnK=Google+%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2

unanswered question: so it means somebody got their head beaten?

Comment: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=busted+in+head&btnK=Google+%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the research you have done, explaining what is left unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Busted in' is not a hairstyle but referring to that his head is cracked. There are some pictures in Google if you type in *Busted in head*. I am not adding the pictures for the reason that it is not for the squeamish.

Answer (score 0):

It just means battered and broken, like beaten up badly. It's not talking about their hairstyle; it's talking about their actual head.